# Paid Billions In Claims

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-meaning, ellipsis

I have a question about this [headline](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/washington/2008-09-23-3541977464_x.htm):

> Medicare paid billions ***in suspect claims***

A "*claim*" is a request for money, not the requested money itself.  So, would the following rewrites of the original headline:

> Medicare paid billions ***in suspect-claims money***
>   Medicare paid billions ***for suspect claims***

be better?

Comment: A claim can also be the [something that is claimed according to Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/claim), for example, money demanded for an insurance settlement.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of the meaning of the sentence is correct.  Congratulations on understanding that "billions" means "billions of (U.S.) dollars", and "claim" means "a request for money".  Compared to those pieces of shorthand, the difference between "in" and "for" is minor.

The expression "<amount of money> in <kind of expense>" is an idiom.  You have correctly understood this idiom as meaning "<amount of money> in <kind of expense> money".  Some examples:

- [Copper thieves cause thousands of dollars in damage.](http://www.ruidosonews.com/ruidoso-opinion/ci_24217813/copper-thieves-cause-thousands-dollars-damage)
- [SEC Charges Bank Executives With Hiding Millions of Dollars in Losses](http://www.sec.gov/news/press/2011/2011-202.htm)

If the sentence had described something valuable that Medicare received in exchange for its money, then "for" would be a better preposition.  For example:

- [Medicare pays about a billion dollars](http://www.bloomberg.com/infographics/2014-04-09/which-medical-specialties-cost-medicare-the-most.html) **for anesthesiology services** every year.
- Medicare pays about a billion dollars **in anesthesiology expenses** every year.
- Medicare pays about a billion dollars **to anesthesiologists** every year.